# Django ViewSet ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project name'

Tags: python, django, url, path, project

I'm trying to use the ModelViewSet to display Users, but for some reason Django does not seem to like the UserViewSet import in project/urls.py. Seems like a pretty silly error, but I've been stuck on this for a while and it's frustrating. I don't have any errors in the code as far as I know and the imports are fully functional. Am I missing something?

Django version 2.2.13

**project/urls.py**

```
from django_backend.user_profile.views import UserViewSet

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('user', UserViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('accounts/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

**userprofile/views.py**

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()#.order_by('-date_joined')
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

**Error**

```
from django_backend.user_profile.views import UserViewSet
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_backend'
```

**Project structure**

[image]

Comment: What's `from django_backend.user_profile.views import UserViewSet`? Your question says that `UserViewSet` is in `userprofile/views.py`, so what's `django_backend`?

Comment: @KenKinder See the project structure. The entire django project lives in django_backend. I use react for my front end.

Comment: Is it a Python package in your python path?

Comment: @KenKinder It's not a python package. The front and back end run completely separately.

Comment: Well, there's your answer. When you import anything, it's got to be either a module in the same directory or a python package in `sys.path`.

Comment: @KenKinder I'm not sure how the parent folder is related to my issue. I might have misinterpreted your question. Django_backend is in fact the django project folder.

Comment: You don't import the project folder. If you set it up as a normal django app, you'd import `user_profile.views`.

Comment: As seen below, I tried this and it works now. But PyCharm still shows it as an error. Any clue why?

Comment: Probably your PyCharm IDE doesn't know where the source root is for Python. I think (?) you can right click on your django_backend folder and choose something like, "Mark Directory As -> Sources Root", although I'm not sure that's exactly the correct way to do it, as that's more a PyCharm question than a Python one.

Comment: @KenKinder Thanks. I actually fixed it by opening django_backend instead of the parent folder. Stupid stupid mistake...

Comment: Ah, sure, it probably defaults to assuming the root folder of your project is the one in your path. But I think you can still open up both your React code and your Django code in PyCharm by opening the root folder of your project, then telling PyCharm that your sources root for Python is the django folder. FWIW, I do the exact opposite in my code; I have a Python root folder, then a frontend folder where my web code lives. PyCharm can edit both JavaScript and Python well, so I only use one editor.

Comment: @KenKinder Ah that's cool, I'll keep that in mind. For now I like to work on them separately. If you want to, you can post an answer and I'll approve it so this question can be closed.

Comment: sure, might help other people. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments, we figured out the direct answer to your question is this: You're importing `django_backend`, which is the root of your project, but isn't a formal [Python package](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) that exists in `sys.path` and thus cannot be imported as such.

Since Django sets `sys.path` to your project's root directory, you'll want to import `user_profile.views` without the `django_backend` part:

```py
from user_profile.views import UserViewSet
```

Once you do that, you might consider configuring PyCharm to know that the `django_backend` folder is your Sources Root. That will tell PyCharm where to look for Python code, so that it doesn't show an error attempting to import modules from your Django directory.

Answer (score 1):

The python interpreter searches for modules in the directories listed in sys.path. You could quickly print sys.path to check whether 'reactjs-comeon' is listed.

Depending on how you ran your file it might not be included. For exemple if you ran project> python urls.py it wouldn't be. You can manually append the directory to sys.path as a quick solution.

In general I would recommend you read-up on relative/absolute imports and packaging on https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Printing sys.path does show the correct structure though: ['C:\\Users\\.....\\reactjs-comeon1\\django_backend'

Comment: Python is searching for the module named ''django_backend" backend within the directories listed. Try just importing user_profile.views.

Comment: This seems to work, but PyCharm is showing it as an error. Weird! https://i.gyazo.com/fa1330ebf22cb43bd0c44a22db4a6970.png